# SNMP Enumeration

Tags: brute-force, enumeration, snmp

I'm scanning a machine that has the **UDP** port **161** open and I'm not able to run `snmpwalk` against it as I'm returned with the error:

```
Timeout: No Response from <IP>
```

I tried to run the `onesixtyone` tool to bruteforce the community string with different wordlists, but with no success.

Is there something else that could be done in that scenario? Is there a way to guess the community string in another way in order to be able to use it along with `snmpwalk`?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options like [snmp-check](https://tools.kali.org/information-gathering/snmp-check), or you can use an [auxiliary scanner](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/snmp-scan/) for Metasploit.

But I think the port which you are trying to access is not up, as snmpwalk should have worked fine. Try to check it with netcat and nmap.

Comment: Nmap and Nessus are reporting the port to be open.

Comment: you can use Wireshark to verify SNMP traffic going through the port
use "snmp" for display filter or "udp port 161 or udp port 162" for capture filter

Comment: Discovered that the SNMP version is 3. Is there a way to enumerate it? I'm only able to retrieve the version number.

Comment: you can try snmpwn for snmp version 3